# Is that possible to transfer bulk data without using hibernate. using jpa,

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
    jdbcTemplate.query("select * from MISDailyCandidateInfo", new RowCallbackHandler() {
        @Override
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMettl = daoFactory.getJDBCTemplateMettl();
            String sql = "insert into TempDailyNDLMCandidatesData (email_id, invitation_id, assessment_id, candidate_reg_id, candidate_context_data)"
                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            while (rs.next()) {
                String emailID = rs.getString("email_id");
                String invitationKey = rs.getString("invitation_key");
                int assessmentID = rs.getInt("assessment_id");
                int candidateRegistrationID = rs.getInt("candidate_reg_id");
                String candidate_context_data = rs.getString("candidate_context_data");
                List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
                params.add(new Object[]{emailID,
                        invitationKey,
                        assessmentID,
                        candidateRegistrationID,
                        candidate_context_data});
                jdbcTemplateMettl.batchUpdate(sql, params);
            }

        }
```

});

1. I am using jdbc for transfer the data from datasource to another datasource it's taking too much time Is there any possibility to transfer  bulk data tranfer form jpa without using model and hibernet

Comment: JPA is an API, it doesn't do anything in itself. You can't download JPA and use it, that's still what you need Hibernate, OpenJPA or EclipseLink for. I am very confused by your question, you say you're already using JDBC to do the work which already is "not hibernate", where does Hibernate fit into this question?

Comment: JPA implementations use JDBC under the covers so what has JPA got to do with speeding this up?!

Comment: @gimby Actually If I will Use JPA then I have to use Hibernet that's hibernet came into the picture

Comment: @Neli Stockton thanks !!!